# How to update WPF UserControl property in StatusBarItem in MainWindow form another UserControl with both having different DataContexts?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I tried searching for answer looking at similar questions but I couldn't find anything that fits this situation.

I have a MainWindow that looks something like this (some parts are omitted):

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:test.Views">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <StatusBar>
                <StatusBarItem>
                    <Views:ProfileView />
                </StatusBarItem>
                <Separator />
                <StatusBarItem>
                    <Views:StatusView />
                </StatusBarItem>
            </StatusBar>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //    some stuff done here
    }
}
```

and two UserControl's:

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.Views.StatusView"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"
     xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:test.ViewModels">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:StatusViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and:

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.Views.ProfileView"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"
     xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:test.ViewModels" MouseEnter="UserControl_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="UserControl_MouseLeave">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:ProfileViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        //    some stuff done here
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

with code-behind:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace test.Views
{
    public partial class StatusView : UserControl
    {
        public StatusView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace test.Views
{
    public partial class ProfileView : UserControl
    {
        public ProfileView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //    Update status bar text
        }

        private void UserControl_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //    Update status bar text
        }
    }
}
```

with each UserControl having it's own ViewModel set as DataContext:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace test.ViewModels
{
    class StatusViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _status = string.Empty;
        public string Status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set { _status = value; OnPropertyChanged("Status"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public StatusViewModel() { }
    }
}
```

and:

```
using System;

namespace test.ViewModels
{
    class ProfileViewModel

        public ProfileViewModel() { }

        //    some stuff done here
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code ProfileView has MouseEnter and MouseLeave events on which I would like to set TextBlock.Text value in StatusView (through it's ViewModel.Status property).

Now not shown here but, other classes should be also able to update value of status bar, in thread-safe way, using the same principle.

How am I to achieve this?

I thought of using DependencyPropertyes or Delegates and Events but, don't know how to do it as, at the moment, both UserControls (and others) are instantiated through XAML in MainWindow, not through code-behind. This is how, I think, it should be done (if I'm to follow MVVM and have separation of work - designer is designing while programmer is programming) but, this is exactly the reason why I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to use MVVM Light.

You can use MVVM Light Messenger. It is a class that allows exchange messages between objects. Messenger class is mainly used for sending messages between viewmodels:
http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger

PS: I also recommend to use command bindings instead of event handlers (that's not MVVM-like).